# contextual meaning of "integrate"

Tags: meaning, expressions, meaning-in-context

In the following sentence, what does "integrate" means?

> Beyond the fact that these processes exacerbate inequalities among
> individuals – those with the most valuable assets are more likely to
> profi t from these new models – they contain the seeds of a
> transformation of individuals, who increasingly integrate financial
> and managerial logics in their own way of functioning.To extract value
> from platform capitalism, individuals must constantly monetize and
> maximize the value of their own assets. *This means, for example, that
> individuals may, when buying a new property, **integrate** the
> potential profit that could be obtained by regularly listing their
> property on Airbnb or another rental platform.*

A dictionary meaning of "integrate" is "to combine two or more things in order to become more effective", but I'm not sure what individuals combine the potential profit with.

I'm confused about contextual meaning of "integrate" in the quoted sentence.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is essential context that's missing. In particular, the one or two sentences that come before what's quoted would likely make it clear what the **potential profit** is being integrated ***with***. Without the context that makes it clear what **this means** is referring to, no answer is possible.

Comment: In this case, it is just a fancy way to say *include* or *take into consideration*. The whole paragraph is written in a high falutin style. The subject isn't that difficult, but it's being made difficult by the author.

Comment: It is much more puzzling what the author means by 'financial and managerial logic**s**'.

Comment: @jsw29 Not only that but the author says "...increasingly integrate financial and managerial logics in their own way of functioning." This is a typical piece of obscurantist jargon, I'm pretty sure that I know what each word means but the meaning of the sentence escapes me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it means that individuals are adding the potential profit from renting out the new property to the change in their wealth by acquiring the property.  (This is clearly speculative as the property may fail to rent, or may fail to rent for the expected value, or may be even accrue costs from rental not covered by it).

For example: if the property were to cost 200,000 (pick your favourite currency) and you expect to rent it out for 2,000 per month, then you might integrate that 2,000 per month into your overall wealth (treating the property as an asset worth 200,000) and say that you are 2,000 per month richer.